# Print a box for every item in a two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, dom, multidimensional-array

Okay so i have a dimensional array and a foor loop which checks each item in the array. There is also a if statment in the loop and it checks if the array-items is === 1. if it is equal to 1 i want to print a 20*20px box. But i don't know how to do that. it works fine if i print something in the console everytime array-item === 1.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var items = "0101101";
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  if (items[i] == 1) {
    document.body.appendChild(
      document.createElement("div")
    );
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write the html for your boxes, give each box a unique id, probably as simple divs like this:

```
 <div class = "box">
 </div>

 css:
 .box{
     background-color: 'black';
     width: 20px;
     height: 20px;
     display: none;
  }
```

This box will be hidden by default. In the Javascript file, on success of your if condition make the box with id corresponding to the index visible by setting the display = block.